# PHP Form to MySQL Embed

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, embed

I have a form for updating my database. The form contains an embed-video-section which calls the embed code on a separate page to display the video in the page.

The problem is that embed links uses `<iframes>` which would be removed by my striptags.

I need some help in safely inserting the embed code from my form to my database.

The embed codes look like this

`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ahg6qcgoay4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

or `<iframe src="http://blip.tv/play/hIVVgfKwRgI.html" width="550" height="339" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: How does the *embed code* look like? Can't you apply it after you've taken the videos from your database?

Comment: I Put the embed codes in the question... i want to have a user be able to put this is a form and save it to my database SAFELY so i can call the code later

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [BBCodes](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://www.sitepoint.com/bb-code-php-application/&rct=j&q=php%20bbcodes%20explanation%20howto&ei=FCpzTo-SG83s-gb82c2sDA&usg=AFQjCNGP3aR79uBv3E_oU1V56Xa0BHz-Fg&sig2=QSfg7vaEIA6Ds9bpce-ijw&cad=rja). For example, `[embed param1=value param2=value]` and so on..

Comment: Thank You I have no clue how to do this but i'll look into it